# Is there any random variable which has unbounded fourth moment?

Tags: pr.probability

In many statements in probability, there is an assumption like bounded fourth moment. So is  there any random variable which has unbounded fourth moment?

Comment: That hypothesis means that a certain integral is finite. You can always arrange that integrals diverge!

Answer (score 8):

An example of a random variable having an infinite fourth moment (and finite lower moments) is the student's t-distributionwith 4 degrees of freedom (see for example the Wikipedia page). 
In general, unless certain conditions are satisfied, ratios of two random variables have infinite moments, the following article by [Cedilnik, Katarina , and Blejec](http://mrvar.fdv.uni-lj.si/pub/mz/mz3.1/cedilnik.pdf) addresses the question of the existence of moments of a ratio of two random variables.

Comment: For example, the Cauchy distribution (mentioned by David Speyer above) is the ratio of two normal random variables with zero mean and unit variance.

Answer (score 5):

More generally, given $p > 1$, take any bounded function on $\mathbb{R}$ which behaves like $1/|x|^p$ as $x\to \infty$, for example $1/(1+|x|^p)$. After renormalizing, this is will be the density of a random variable which has finite absolute $q$th moments for $0 \le q < p-1$, and infinite $q$th moments for $q \ge p-1$.

Comment: An example of this type that has a name is the Pareto distribution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution)

Answer (score 3):

What about just taking the real valued random variable which lands in the interval $(x, x+dx)$ with probability $(1/\pi) dx/(1+x^2)$? The fourth moment is

$$\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{x^4 dx}{(1+x^2)}$$

which is extremely divergent.

Comment: This even has a name--it's the Cauchy distribution.

Comment: I assumed the question was more specific: infinite fourth moment, and finite third moment.